# DbSet method throws NotImplementedException when called inside of controller

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm in trouble and these are my settings

**My Context:**

```
public partial class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext() : base("MyConnectionString")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Categories> Categories { get; set; }
```

**The GetSingle method:**

```
public virtual T GetSingle(Func<T, bool> where, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties)
    {
        try
        {
            T item = null;
            using (var context = new MyContext())
            {
                IQueryable<T> dbQuery = context.Set<T>().AsQueryable();
                if (!navigationProperties.Any())
                    return dbQuery.Where(where).FirstOrDefault();
                foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
                {
                    dbQuery = dbQuery.Include(navigationProperty);

                    item = dbQuery
                        .AsNoTracking()
                        .Where(where)
                        .FirstOrDefault();
                }
            }
            return item;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
```

**In my controller i call:**

```
var categories = CategoriesControl.GetSingle(x => x.Active == true).OrderBy(x => x.Name);
```

When executing the GetSingle method I get the following exception:

> The member 'Local' has not been implemented on type 'CategoriesControl' which inherits from 'DbSet`1'. Test doubles for 'DbSet`1' must provide implementations of methods and properties that are used.

I don't know how to solve this problem. I need some help

Comment: How are you going to get single and after this order it?

Answer (score 0):

How are you going to get single and after this order it? You can't sort a single item. It doesn't make any sense. This is why OrderBy is not implemented for work with a single item. Try this:

```
var categories = CategoriesControl.Where(x => x.Active == true).OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

or if you need Top 1 of the collection:

```
var category = CategoriesControl.Where(x => x.Active == true).OrderBy(x => x.Name).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Exactly no snippets return dbQuery.Where (where) .FirstOrDefault (); in the GetSingle method the code throws an exception

Comment: But your case is dbQuery.Where (where) .FirstOrDefault ().OrderBy(). You can't orderby a single item. It doesn't make any sense. This is why OrderBy is not implemented for work with a single item.

Comment: When the Categories Control property is filled in the controller constructor by calling CategorieControl = (ICategorieControl)controlFactory.Instance<CategoryCompany>(); I already see an inner exception, even before executing the GetSingle method.